# What does it mean when the return type on a UML Diagram is an object?

Tags: java, class, methods, uml, class-diagram

[image: UML Diagram]

The class Chess has a method called `knighMoves(int i, int j): Chess` with `Chess` as the return type. Would the method header be

```
public static Chess knightMoves(int i, int j)
{
   return
}
```

What would the return statement entail?

Comment: It means what it looks like. The method returns an instance of `Chess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model tells us that  the operation `knightMoves()` is not static (static members should be underlined in the diagram), and it returns a `Chess` object.

You may be confused because the return type is also the enclosing class.  But this does not change anything. The java method would look like:

```
public Chess knightMoves(int i, int j)
{
   Chess game;
   … // some code that would assign a value to game
       // and or change its state
   return game; 
}
```

or depending on your design intent:

```
public Chess knightMoves(int i, int j)
{
   … // some code that changes the current object
   return this; // return enclosing object
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much!